# How to split the CSV file using python without datatype change?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, boolean

I have 35M records CSV file with 160 columns. I need to split 7 CSV files(5M records) from 35M records CSV file. I have used **pandas** for the split process.

when I try to split the records, it shows a warning message. But, the split process successfully finished.

**sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (27,28,32,33,34,42,44,49,57,59,60,61,62,71,72,82,94,96,97,103,123,124,125,149,150,151) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.**

split CSV file datatypes are changed. The boolean datatype values are changed to float datatype.

**Before split: boolean values -  0 , 1**

**After split: boolean values -  0.0 , 1.0**

During the split process, I declared the datatypes for each column.

`dtype={'id' : str,'name' : str,'flag' : bool}`

But, it not working for this issue.

How to fix this issue??

Comment: What's not working ?

Comment: Please paste your code here